# "If/When" my father hit me with a stick, I "used/would" jump and run away - what are the differences?

Tags: conditionals

Below are past real conditional examples:

**Example 1**

> If my father hit me with a stick, I **used to** jump and run away.

**Example 2**

> If my father hit me with a stick, I **would** jump and run away.

What is the difference?

They are both telling a past real condition, right?

---

Below are past real habit statement examples:

**Example 3**

> When my father hit me with a stick, I **used to** jump and run away.

**Example 4**

> When my father hit me with a stick, I **would** jump and run away.

What is the difference?

They are both telling a past habit, right?

Comment: This has been asked before.  Please do a search for duplicates.

Comment: _Would_ in this sense refers to a habitual action, so it is the same as _used to_.

Comment: So far as I'm concerned, they both "mean" exactly the same. The difference is that the "used to" version is a bit more "relaxed conversational English", and the "would" version is a bit more "literary".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would and used to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118175/would-and-used-to). Also [Past simple vs used to vs would](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49816/past-simple-vs-used-to-vs-would) and *many* more.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so the examples 1-4 are all correct? What is the difference between "when" and "if" there? And do "used" to and "would" mean almost the same in "When/if" my father hit me with a stick, I used to/would jump and run away?

Comment: I already said "used to" and "would" are slightly different "registers". I can't see even the slightest difference between using "when" and "if" *in this exact context*, because regardless of whether it's "used to" or "would", that "habitual reaction" clause tells us this *isn't* a situation where it's irrelevant that "if" usually implies ***but possibly not***. So there's simply no *scope* for different meanings there. It's not like, say, ***If / When** you do this, I'll do that*, which obviously have two very different meanings.

Comment: ...you should also remember that just as I wouldn't see any difference between "if" and "when" in your examples ***as a reader***, I'd be quite capable of ***writing*** either version myself in a similar context. So if anyone else assures you there ***is*** a difference, you need to bear in mind that they may well be ascribing some kind of significance to a writer's choice of phrasing that the writer himself doesn't recognize! And almost *nothing* about language reflects any underlying "truth". Words only mean what people *say* they mean, and ***not all Anglophones agree on everything***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your explanation. Can you explain the following sentence in plain English, that "habitual reaction" clause tells us this isn't a situation where it's irrelevant that "if" usually implies but possibly not. "? I cannot comprehend it well, thank you.

Comment: The way the "reaction / result" *(I jumped and ran away)* is worded (whether it's "used to" or "would") implies this happened *regularly / routinely / often*. Since that's a reaction to being hit by the father, it follows that the father doing that was *also* "routine". Consequently there's no scope for the "if / when" choice to imply anything different. Well, maybe someone could claim that "if" implies less frequently than "when". But then someone else might claim the opposite!